# groupby nightime with varying hours

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to calculate night-time averages of a dataframe except that what I need is a mix between daily average and hour range average.
More specifically, I have a dataframe storing day and night hours and I want to use it as a boolean key to calculate night-time averages of another dataframe.
I cannot use daily averages because each night spreads over two calendar days, and I cannot use by hour range either because hours change by season.

Thanks for your help!
Dariush.

Based on comments received here is what I am looking for - see spreadsheet below. I need to calculate the average of 'Value' during nighttime using the Nighttime flag, and then repeat the average value for all time stamps until the following night, at which time the average is updated and repeated until the next nighttime flag.
[image]

Comment: Sample and expected output please :)

Comment: Do you want one nighttime average and one daytime average, or one average for each day and night?

Comment: What’s the exact issue you’re facing? Stack Overflow is not the place to dump off your work for others to do.